# Install .NET standard 2.1

Tags: c#

Trying to open C# project in my Windows 10 system, Visual Studio 2019. Project is created with .NET Standard 2.1,  but looks like it is not supported in my system:

> Error NU1201
> Project App is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP, Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-x64-aot.
> Project App supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard, Version=v2.1) App.UWP

If I downgrade to .NET Standard 2.0, I'm getting [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76295384/the-type-or-namespace-name-is-missing?noredirect=1#comment134541039_76295384).

How to solve this problem? How to install .NET Standard 2.1 on my system?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install .NET Core 3 (or later) for [.NET Standard 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1) capabilities.

At the time of writing, I suggest .NET 6 or later. [Releases and support for .NET (.NET 5+ and .NET Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/releases-and-support).

For development, you will want the SDK, not just the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `App.UWP` in the error message gives me the hint that this is a UWP app, which simply isn't compatible with .NET Standard 2.1.

Possible solutions:

- You must target .NET Standard 2.0 in your referenced project. UWP projects are able to use such a dependent library if you target at least Windows 10.0.16299.0 (Fall Creators Update, version 1709). But as you noticed, .NET Standard 2.0 supports much less API than .NET Standard 2.1
- Another solution if you change your application project type to a more modern one such as WinUI 3 or MAUI. If you want to target Windows only, then a WinUI project can be the simplest solution (maybe you can even reuse your views and view models without any change created for the UWP app). This is the recommended solution if it's not a problem that it requires to target at least .NET 5 and Windows 10.0.17763.0 (October 2018 release, version 1809). But frankly, I don't think this is a real barrier today.

See a couple of examples for the same demo application in [UWP](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/tree/master/Examples/Uwp) and [WinUI](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/tree/master/Examples/WinUI) behind the links. The UWP one can work only because the dependencies of the referenced package all support .NET Standard 2.0 as it's emphasized on its [README](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.Uwp#readme-body-tab) tab.